# Error 411 when using POST request in WSO2 API Manager

Tags: curl, wso2, http-post, wso2-api-manager, fiware

I have created an API via the WSO2 API Manager curl GET requets work fine as you can see below:

[image: GET request]

But when trying to setup a POST request I get the following message "error 411: Length required"

[image: error 411 message]

I have tried different things such as disabling chunking or forcing content length header (as WSO2 removes that header by default) by changing the sequence file as shown below but to no avail:

[image: custom sequence file]

And what is strange is that I use command prompt to make the same post request it works even I do not specify the `content-length` header which suggest that it is added automatically (correct me if I am wrong):

[image: command prompt post request]

There must be something I am doing wrong could you please help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second cUrl request looks a bit strange for two reasons:

A valid NGSI-v2 POST request looks something like:

```
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/v2/entities/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
   Body Goes HERE
}'
```

Your image contains the headers `Content-Length=aux` and `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` and the `-d` element is not quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to sort this problem by using the following inSequence (mediation file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="contentLengthadd">
        <property name="COPY_CONTENT_LENGTH_FROM_INCOMING" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="FORCE_HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH" scope="axis2" value="true"></property>
</sequence>
```

By default, WSO2 removes the content-length header therefore you need to make sure it will be added. What this sequence does is that it calculates the payload to be sent then it added the value number for the content-length header.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/411 for the 411 error you get.
The 411 error will be thrown when the content-length header is not passed in the curl request.

- The images you have shared in the link are not clear. Please upload the images again or share the curl command and the response which is more convenient.
- Share the sequence in text format.
- If you remove the sequence, is the server still throwing the error?